# Youtube embedded video activating too late to accept javascript call

Tags: javascript, flash, youtube

I have a YouTube video embedded in my page. It is hidden (display:none). You need to click one of the video link buttons to display the video and play it. The links are defined like this:

```
<a href="javascript:play('xxxxxxxxxxx')">Video 1</a>
<a href="javascript:play('xxxxxxxxxxx')">Video 2</a>
```

*xxxxxxxxx represent YouTube video IDs.*

Here's the play function:

```
function play(id)
{
    ytplayer.style.display = 'block';
    ytplayer.loadVideoById( id, 0, 'hd1080' );
}
```

It's fundamentally pretty simple! But here's the problem. since the video player is hidden, the flash object is not activated. So when I click a video link, the line `ytplayer.style.display = 'block';` displays the video player, but it takes about about half a second for flash to load. During this time it cannot accept any method calls, such as the next line `ytplayer.loadVideoById( id, 0, 'hd1080' );`. Essentially, I have to click the link twice, once to load up the flash video player, the second time to actually load the video into the player.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like once you enable the video, you need to setup and wait for a callback:

```
onYouTubePlayerReady(playerid)
```

(Taken from this page: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html)

In that function you could then do any calls that require the player to be loaded:

```
ytplayer.loadVideoById( id, 0, 'hd1080' );
```

If you aren't using the chromeless player, you may need to instead listen for the onStateChange and onError events.

Comment: I tried that, it only appears to dispatch that event when the player is first loaded into the page. Before it is hidden. After it is displayed again, this event doesn't fire.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa, you say "this event", which do you mean?

Comment: The even that triggers `onYouTubePlayerReady`. I mean to say that `onYouTubePlayerReady` is only called during the initial load.